# AWS Glue creates struct when long is present

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a Glue job that is reading a bunch of JSON files from S3, creates a DynamicFrame and writes the output on another S3 bucket.

From those files I am selecting a field `id`. Up until recently, that was a small number and could fit into a Spark IntegerType (max: 2147483647). Now I am starting to see larger numbers that should be of type LongType.

Creating the DynamicFrame in Glue:

```
data_source = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={"paths": paths},
    format='json',
    transformation_ctx='data_source',
    format_options={"jsonPath": "$[*]"}
)
```

Reading the selected fields:

```
df = SelectFields.apply(frame=data_source, paths=['id', ...])
df.toDF().printSchema()
```

The problem: Glue creates a `struct` instead of a `long` and that messes the whole job.

```
root
 |-- id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- int: int (nullable = true)
 |    |-- long: bigint (nullable = true)
```

Example: for an `id` with value `5.000.000.000.000` the struct is `[, 5000000000000]` and for an `id` with value `1.000.000` the struct is `[1000000,]`.

Question: how do I prevent Glue for doing this? I want to parse all to a long type.

Thanks!

**Update**

It seems that some records were processed even if the value of the id was clearly long. So it seems that not always (?) Glue creates the struct.

**Another update**

It seems that it's an expected behavior of Glue whenever it feels it cannot determine the real data type. That's why there is this class `ResolveChoice` to allow you to select a default value. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-ResolveChoice.html

Using this class to choose the type I want solved my issue. For example if I have an `id = [long=None, int=10] or id = [long=10, int=None]` (for the sake of the example), using `df = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = raw_df, choice = "cast:long")` will give me for both cases `id=10` and type `long`.

Hope this helps others! ;)